# how to read hindi text from Ms Access database in java using JDBC?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am creating an java application which is used to read Hindi Data from ms access Database. 
please suggest me how to read Hindi text in java from ms access database.

code :

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+db_path+";";  // setup the properties
            java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
            prop.put("charSet", "UTF-8");
            prop.put("user", "");
            prop.put("password", "");



        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, prop);
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way SO works. If you have code which causes problems you can come back. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MateuszSroka please answer if you can

Answer (score 1):

Java's JDBC-ODBC Bridge and the Access ODBC driver will not be able to retrieve the Unicode (Hindi) text from the database. However, the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver can do it. See:

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)